# Meteor count the value of two collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I got a collection `Projects` and a collection `Questions`. Each `Project` has got an document 'Accepted ', with an array of accepted users.
Each `Question` has a document 'Project' with the projectId.

Example situation:
There are 6 questions. Project 1 has got two questions, project 2 has got 2 questions, and project 3 has got 2 questions. 
 User X has accepted project 2 and project 3.

I want to return the amount of questions that User X has got.

```
return Projects.find({accepted: currentUser}); // Gives two projectId's
```

And then each projectId:

```
return Questions.find({project: <projectId>}).count();
```

and add all the amounts of questions for each projectId.

How am I supposed to do that?

Yours,
L

Comment: Can you add sample document with the expected result to your question?

Comment: `return Questions.find({project: {$in: [projectIds]}}).count();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a multi-step query for each project Id, you can use a single mongodb selector which matches any of the ID's that are returned from an initial query.

The selector for that would be [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

So in your case, the solution would be:

```
// get the current user's id (you can use this.userId if you are in a method or a publication
const currentUser = Meteor.userId();

// we want an array of _id's only
const projectIds = Projects.find({accepted: currentUser}).map(function(project) {
  return project._id;
})

// now we use the $in operator
return Questions.find({project: {$in: projectIds} }).count();
```